# Is there an OSX build-in alternative for Windows 7 Presentation mode?

Tags: windows-7, macos, presentations

On Windows 7 there is a **Presentation mode**, which can be turned on using the Windows Mobility Center (press winkey-x to open it). 
The Presentation mode disables the screensaver, screen dimming, changes wallpaper etc.

Is there a build-in alternative for Mac OSX ?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you can use applescript to do this if you need it to be "built-in". However I use a free app called caffeine:

http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/

which does this, and I've made two additional applescript apps so I can control caffeinating and decaffeinating my mac using quicksilver. As a coffee addict I love seeing the cup of coffee in my menu bar too :)

caffeinate.app

```
tell application "Caffeine"
    turn on
end tell
```

decaffeinate.app

```
tell application "Caffeine"
    turn off
end tell
```

Comment: Since you're scripting it, have you found a way to remove the icon completely? Replacing the image resource file just isn't good enough. By the way, with one-liners, you can do `tell application "Caffeine" to turn on`.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: No.

But you could give [AirPort Location](http://airportlocationformac.com/) a try. With this menu extra you can define "Snapshots" (configuring a lot of settings from screensaver to desktop background to brightness of the screen) and activate them either manually or even by your current location (as determined via Wi-Fi or connected Devices, etc..).